# Codeigniter HTML & Apache, JPG & jpg

Tags: html, codeigniter, jpeg, image-uploading

Hi i'm using codeigniter to save some jpg/JPG files on the webserver.
The problem is i don't know if all of the files extension will be the same: jpg/JPG
so on rendering i put a tag like this

```
<img src="/.../name.JPG"/>
```

in this way if the uploaded file is a .jpg it will not be displayed.

the solution i'm going to use is a simple redundance of the tag HTML:

```
<img src="/.../name.JPG"/> 
<img src="/.../name.jpg"/>
```

this way if one is not rendered the other is

i would like to know if this problem can be resolved in php or codeigniter by changing the file extension on upload.

Comment: Change the extension to lower when uploading the file? Seems the simplest solution to me.

Answer (score 1):

```
$newname = basename($filename, ".JPG").".jpg";
rename($filename, $newname);
```